# Separate bibliography in each chapter, and general bibliography in the end, without biblatex package

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, back-referencing

I'm using `backref` package to have hyperlinks in my bibliography. I would like to create one bibliography for each chapter (but links only within the chapter, for example if T1 is cited in chapter 1 and chapter 2, chapter's 2 bibliography's should only mention the reference in chapter 2), with a general bibliography in the end refering all the citations.

I read that it could be done using the `biblatex` package, which I tried, but I can't use it because I'm using the `backref` package.

A Minimal Working Example can be found [here](http://ovh.to/8ZnE4id). The example is working pdflatex-wise, but bibtex outputs an error because of the two bib files and creates only one bibliography that is therefore found 3 times in the file.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote, you don't want to use biblatex instead of bibtex due to the backref packge. Maybe you could replace the backref-package with biblatex's "backref=true" option and therefor achieve the desired bibliographies using biblatex and the code you already tried.

Comment: Using biblatex and removing backref works and does exactly what I want, except for the global bibliography at the end. Any idea on how I can do that?

Comment: I just tried nesting refsections but the compiler told me I can't.

Answer (score 1):

OK I made it work using the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book} 
\usepackage[english]{minitoc}
\usepackage[backref=true,refsegment=chapter]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  backrefpage = {page},% originally "cited on page"
  backrefpages = {pages},% originally "cited on pages"
}

\bibliography{All.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chap 1}
Test 1 \cite{T1} and test \cite{T2}.
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment]

\chapter{Chap 2}
Test 3 \cite{T3} and test 4 \cite{T4} and again test 1 \cite{T1}.
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment]

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

It did exactly what I wanted. Thanks leandriis for your precious help!